# Apple rejected my app for problems with IPv6 (crashing)

Tags: ios, ipv6

I have an App that doesn't use internet connexion, but apple send me a message where says that I have a crash in my first view controller for problem with the IPv6. Apple send me a report for the crash but i'm not able to learn it, i need your help. Or maybe if u had the same problem with this conexión(IPv6) and you were find the error.

pleas help me!!

Heres one file from the crash, that apple send me but i don't understand, pleas help me to know what they say.

---

```
{"app_name":"idWallet","timestamp":"2017-03-03 19:35:40.34 -0800","app_version":"1.1","slice_uuid":"7670eb49-b5ca-3334-b398-6cdb6982530e","adam_id":0,"build_version":"3","bundleID":"fernandorey.idWallet","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 10.2.1 (14D27)","incident_id":"195A9217-8AF8-47BA-A8C2-4FC808AF587F","name":"idWallet"}
Incident Identifier: 195A9217-8AF8-47BA-A8C2-4FC808AF587F
CrashReporter Key:   0ec021c8a7f1efb30dfc7eceb07eaa3fd8f82c46
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             idWallet [8539]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E974F007-2A8F-4724-A766-6E542BCDD035/idWallet.app/idWallet
Identifier:          fernandorey.idWallet
Version:             3 (1.1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           fernandorey.idWallet [4123]


Date/Time:           2017-03-03 19:35:40.1752 -0800
Launch Time:         2017-03-03 19:26:24.4423 -0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.2.1 (14D27)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x18e1a91b8 0x18cbe055c 0x1904c0b90 0x10005f17c 0x10005e8c8 0x194057924 0x1940574ec 0x194a19cf0 0x1943a24ac 0x1943c3a54 0x1943c6920 0x19414a154 0x1943ca0e4 0x194706808 0x194814854 0x19481465c 0x1943ba9b8 0x100067b98 0x100068804 0x10006841c 0x100068218 0x19408cd30 0x19408ccb0 0x194077128 0x19408c59c 0x19408c0c4 0x194087328 0x194057da0 0x19484175c 0x19483b130 0x18e156b5c 0x18e1564a4 0x18e1540a4 0x18e0822b8 0x18fb36198 0x1940c27fc 0x1940bd534 0x10005d3b4 0x18d0655b8)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018d177014 0x18d158000 + 126996
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018d23f450 0x18d23a000 + 21584
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018d0eb400 0x18d088000 + 406528
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018cbb52d4 0x18cbb4000 + 4820
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018cbd2cc0 0x18cbb4000 + 126144
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018cbe0844 0x18cbd8000 + 34884
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018cbcf66c 0x18cbb4000 + 112236
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018cbcf234 0x18cbb4000 + 111156
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018cbe071c 0x18cbd8000 + 34588
9   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018e08232c 0x18e079000 + 37676
10  GraphicsServices                0x000000018fb36198 0x18fb2a000 + 49560
11  UIKit                           0x00000001940c27fc 0x194048000 + 501756
12  UIKit                           0x00000001940bd534 0x194048000 + 480564
13  idWallet                        0x000000010005d3b4 0x100054000 + 37812
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018d0655b8 0x18d061000 + 17848

Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018d159188 0x18d158000 + 4488
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018d158ff8 0x18d158000 + 4088
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018e1565d0 0x18e079000 + 906704
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018e1541ec 0x18e079000 + 897516
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018e0822b8 0x18e079000 + 37560
5   Foundation                      0x000000018ebbf26c 0x18ebb3000 + 49772
6   Foundation                      0x000000018ebdfdd0 0x18ebb3000 + 183760
7   UIKit                           0x0000000194a36c38 0x194048000 + 10415160
8   Foundation                      0x000000018ecbce68 0x18ebb3000 + 1089128
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018d23d850 0x18d23a000 + 14416
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018d23d760 0x18d23a000 + 14176
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018d23ad94 0x18d23a000 + 3476

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018d23ad88 0x18d23a000 + 3464

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018d23ad88 0x18d23a000 + 3464

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018d23ad88 0x18d23a000 + 3464

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001780e8437
    x4: 0x000000018cbd3bc3   x5: 0x000000016fdab520   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x000000000000000b  x11: 0x0000000000000010
   x12: 0x000000018d102772  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000040000000400  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001b3219c40  x21: 0x000000016fdab520  x22: 0x00000001b3220bb8  x23: 0x0000000000000001
   x24: 0x0000000178018be0  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000001  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x000000016fdabbc0   fp: 0x000000016fdab480   lr: 0x000000018d23f450
    sp: 0x000000016fdab460   pc: 0x000000018d177014 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

.
.
.

---

i can't add all the message for question of limit characters.

Comment: `Application Specific Information:
abort() called`. Are you explicitly calling `abort` somewhere?

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash report.  It probably doesn't have anything to do with ipv6, the reviewer just happened to be connected to an ipv6 network when it crashed.

Comment: @Carcigenicate i'm not calling the abort() in any case

Answer (score 0):

As @dan mentioned, try to symbolicate your crash report.

The following link will help you.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-SYMBOLICATEWITHXCODE